# Force a page to detach in client script

Tags: google-app-maker

We have a page that takes a while to load the first time. The second time it loads fine. We tried the following hack in the startup script:

```
 var page = app.currentPage;
 app.showPage(app.pages.bigForm);
 app.showPage(page);
```

This hack does work, the page loads fast the first time it is accessed by the user. The screen does not flash between the loads. However, the `bigform` does not detach and the first time it is opened it does not execute the on-attach event. This event contains some code I would like to execute.

My questions:

- is there a better way of doing this, basically pre-loading the page?
- is there a way to force a detach of the page?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to start from looking for causes of slow load. Most common reasons are:

**Large number of widgets to render** (this will cause rendering throttle)

There are no much things you can do in this case:

- Split page into multiple pages
- If you have widgets that you need to show conditionally you can use `createChildren method is called` option in panel's Performance Settings instead of particular widgets' `visible` settings

**Heavy queries to server or big number of queries**

To tune app's performance in this scenario you can try these tricks:

- eagerly load some datasources on app start
- Use datasource prefetches for relational data (this easy tweak usually gives huge performance boost)

Comment: Fair answer, however there are cases where the form can't easily be split up. And it is also trying to understand the system. For example if I add a timeout before opening the previous page, then the bigForm does detach. This seems strange to me, app.ShowPage does not seem to wait for the previous page to unload?

Comment: App Maker isn't really transparent with widgets/pages life cycle (https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/widgets#widget_life_cycle, https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/logic#Events). If it doesn't state or provide something explicitly, then most likely it would be hard to achieve.